# How to force a submit button in iframe to open in parent window

Tags: iframe

I have a page being embedded into iframe.
The iframe contains a form and submit button.
I am trying to make the submit button then load result into the parent (not the iframe).
I have tried base=parent in head and also in the button/form target but it does not work.

URL inside iframe : https://www.purelocal.com.au/search-iframe
When the 1st form is submitted - it does load in parent.
When the 1st and 2nd form are submitted - it DOES NOT load in parent.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way of doing this is to add the following to the top of the results page, this will force it to reload where you want it.

```
if(window.top!==window.self) {
  window.top.location=window.self.location
}
```

The perhaps better way would be to read in all the data on your form, then use JS to recreate the form on the parent page and submit it from there.